# LogStash failed action with response of 500, dropping action

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am trying to configure LogStash to watch a file and send events to elasticsearch server.

When I start logstash to output to stdout, it runs fine:

```
stdout { 
    codec => rubydebug
}
```

But when I add elasticsearch output:

```
elasticsearch {
    cluster => 'myclustername'
    host => 'myip'
    node_name => 'Aragorn'
}
```

Logstash starts up

```
Mar 16, 2015 3:44:24 PM org.elasticsearch.node.internal.InternalNode <init>
INFO: [Aragorn] version[1.4.0], pid[7136], build[bc94bd8/2014-11-05T14:26:12Z]
Mar 16, 2015 3:44:24 PM org.elasticsearch.node.internal.InternalNode <init>
INFO: [Aragorn] initializing ...
Mar 16, 2015 3:44:24 PM org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService <init>
INFO: [Aragorn] loaded [], sites []
Mar 16, 2015 3:44:25 PM org.elasticsearch.node.internal.InternalNode <init>
INFO: [Aragorn] initialized
Mar 16, 2015 3:44:25 PM org.elasticsearch.node.internal.InternalNode start
INFO: [Aragorn] starting ...
Mar 16, 2015 3:44:25 PM org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService doStart
INFO: [Aragorn] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9300]}, publish_address {inet[/10.98.134.83:9300]}
Mar 16, 2015 3:44:25 PM org.elasticsearch.discovery.DiscoveryService doStart
INFO: [Aragorn] myclustername/RjasP2X0ShKXEl0f2WRxBA
Mar 16, 2015 3:44:30 PM org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.InternalClusterService$UpdateTask run
INFO: [Aragorn] detected_master [Aragorn][0YytUoWlQ2qgw2_0i5V4mQ][SOMEMACHINE][inet[/myip:9300]], added {[Aragorn][0YytUoWlQ2qgw2_0i5V4mQ][
SOMEMACHINE][inet[/myip:9300]],}, reason: zen-disco-receive(from master [[Aragorn][0YytUoWlQ2qgw2_0i5V4mQ][SOMEMACHINE][inet[/myip:9300]]])
Mar 16, 2015 3:44:30 PM org.elasticsearch.node.internal.InternalNode start
INFO: [Aragorn] started
```

But when messages start coming in, nothing is in fact sent to elasticsearch and these start to appear in logstash output:

```
WARNING: [Aragorn] Message not fully read (response) for [28] handler org.elasticsearch.action.support.master.TransportMasterNodeOperationAction$6@17b
531e, error [true], resetting
Mar 16, 2015 3:44:54 PM org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler messageReceived
WARNING: [Aragorn] Message not fully read (response) for [29] handler org.elasticsearch.action.support.master.TransportMasterNodeOperationAction$6@130
82f0, error [true], resetting
```

and

```
{:timestamp=>"2015-03-16T15:44:54.377000+0100", :message=>"failed action with response of 500, dropping action...
```

(the above message is much longer but does not seem to contain any useful diagnostics)

What might be wrong?

Comment: Does the version of the embedded Elasticsearch in Logstash match that of the Elasticsearch cluster itself? Make sure the versions are the same at least to the minor # (e.g. 1.4).